# Server - read parameters from a request (post)

Tags: android

i have the following code in my client:

```
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    EditText etxt_user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText etxt_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    String username1 = etxt_user.getText().toString();
    String password1 = etxt_pass.getText().toString();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888");
    Log.v(TAG, "message1");         
    //add your Data
    List< BasicNameValuePair > nvps = new ArrayList< BasicNameValuePair >();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username1));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password1));

    try {
          UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
          httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
          //Execute HTTP Post Request
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

          Log.v(TAG,"message2");
          Log.v(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());
          HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

And my web service has the following code:

```
public Source invoke(Source request){
        String replyElement = new String("hello world");
        StreamSource reply = new StreamSource(new StringReader(replyElement));
        String replyElement2 = new String("hello world 2");
        StreamSource reply2 =  new StreamSource(new StringReader(replyElement2));
        String amount = null;
        if (ws_ctx == null)throw new RuntimeException("DI failed on ws_ctx.");
        if (request == null) {
            System.out.println("Getting input from query string");
            // Grab the message context and extract the request verb.
            MessageContext msg_ctx = ws_ctx.getMessageContext();
            String x = msg_ctx.toString();
            System.out.println("The value" + x + "was received from the client");
            String http_verb = (String)msg_ctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD);
            System.out.println(http_verb);
            String query = (String)msg_ctx.get(MessageContext.QUERY_STRING);
            System.out.println("Query String = " + query);   
            if(query == null)
            {
                System.out.println("The query variable has zero value!!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The value of the query variable is:" + query);
            }

            http_verb = http_verb.trim().toUpperCase()

        } else {
            System.out.println("Getting input from input message");
            Node n = null;
            if (request instanceof DOMSource) {
                n = ((DOMSource) request).getNode();
            } else if (request instanceof StreamSource) {
                StreamSource streamSource = (StreamSource) request;
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource inputSource = null;
                if (streamSource.getInputStream() != null) {
                    inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getInputStream());
                } else if (streamSource.getReader() != null) {
                    inputSource = new InputSource(streamSource.getReader());
                }
                n = db.parse(inputSource);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported source: " + request);
            }

        }

    return reply2;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new HTTPException(500);
    }

}
```

}

The client communicates with the server, but the server reads the parameters username and password only when i put the parameters in the URL like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888"+"?username=" + username1 + "&password=" + password1);
```

How can the server read the parameters from the entity body? I am trying to send the parameters from the client using this line:

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Isn't it better to pass the parameters in the entity body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following and see if it works (I've used it before)

```
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity("username=" + username1 + "&password=" + password1);         
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(path);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setEntity(params);
```

Hope it works for you as well.

And if you are working on very simple Server side (as your question suggested) you might want to look at other framework that I mentioned below. Primarily look at this code example for JAX-RS:

```
    @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        public void newTodo(
                @FormParam("id") String id,
                @FormParam("summary") String summary,
                @FormParam("description") String description,
                @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
        ) throws IOException {
            Todo todo = new Todo(id,summary);
            if (description!=null){
                todo.setDescription(description);
            }
            TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(id, todo);

            URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(id).build();
            Response.created(uri).build();

            servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_todo.html");
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately no! :( I can't understand what i am doing wrong! Maybe the code of the server is wrong. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Hi what you are trying to do on the server? I am guessing you are using JAX-WS to build your REST. JAX-WS is mostly used to manipulate XML in POST (and thus the Source in request). If you are building simple REST service (as suggested by your question), you might want to check http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html or alternatively another popular Java REST framework http://www.restlet.org/

Comment: I've provided the sample from http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html that you might be looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I am trying to implement a chat application. As i have read and as some people suggested to me a REST implementation with JSON is a good choice. It is the first time i am using REST so I am trying to figure out how it works. You really helped me. Thank you once again!

Comment: Yes, JSON would definitely make more sense since it is lighter. Those two frameworks should help you out. Good luck and if you need more help, don't hesitate to post more questions :)

Comment: @ momo i need your help. I am reading the vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html. So the tomcat(web container) runs in the web service in order to manage the servlets? Is this part of the jersey implementation or we can also not use the tomcat. I am working in eclipse classic, can i make it suitable in some way for jersey or i have to download the Eclipse WTP, and how i can add the required jar(A zip of Jersey containing the Jersey jars). I know silly questions but i am trying to understand.

Comment: You can choose not to use Tomcat, but you still need a web container. Jersey works with various container such as GlashFish, JBoss, etc. You don't need Eclipse WTP, but it will make your live easier and you don't need to redownload the entire Eclipse. You can download it on top of your current installation. See http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse for instruction on how to do it. I am about to fly out, but I'll check back once I land

Comment: @Anna, did you get your container working? Let me know if you need more hints

Comment: Just a "thank you" is not enough! Everything works fine now. :) Thank you! I have some queries about the android client but i will search about it first and probably come back. :)